# Solr search/faceting results have strange behaviour: i only get "stemmed" strings (hope it's correct definition)

Tags: filter, solr, stemming, facet

Sorry for a title that bad, but i didn't know how to describe my problem.
I'm using sunburnt (python interface) to query solr within my django app.
When i'm searching, everything is ok, i get the full string.
On the other hand, if i'm faceting (let's say on "job_title" field) i'm getting only the stemmed words

Like this:

```
<lst name="job_title">
    <int name="manag">17095</int>
    <int name="sale">7689</int>
    <int name="engin">6995</int>
    <int name="consult">4907</int>
    <int name="account">4710</int>
    <int name="develop">4509</int>
    <int name="senior">4366</int>
```

and so on...
This is my text fieldType definition:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

i think the PorterStemFilter is the one screwing things up, but i need it to activate suggestions. Any help?

Comment: if you think my question's title is bad, suggestions here are well accepted to change it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you usually facet on unanalyzed fields. Add another field with StrField type, use a copyField directive to get the data there, and facet on this new string field.

Comment: thanks, this works :) wasn't actually what i was thinking, but since i didn't think about it, i'm going with this solution :) thanks again!